# simplify the following rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the following
$$
\frac{x^2-x-2}{x^2-3x} \times \frac{x^2-x-6}{x^2+5x+4}
$$

I don't know how to approach it. I tried doing the quadratics first but now I'm stuck after getting
$$
\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{x(x-3)} \times \frac{(x-2)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x+4)}
$$

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{x^2-x-2}{x^2-3x}\cdot \frac{x^2-x-6}{x^2+5x+4}$$?

Comment: There are some obvious cancellations to make now that you've factored several of the terms.

Comment: You should be able to cancel out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a \cdot c}{b \cdot d}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

I'd check your factoring of the right numerator, though.  One of the terms should have a plus sign.

Next, note that you can cancel equal factors in the numerator and denominator.

For example, $(x+1)$ is in both numerator and denominator, so you can cancel those.  (It's the same as $1$.)

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2-x-2}{x^2-3x} \times \frac{x^2-x-6}{x^2+5x+4}$$

**Step#1**

Factorize them,

$$\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{x(x-3)} \times \frac{(x+2)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x+4)}$$

**Step#2**

Use the *Associativity of Multiplication* such that the linear factors, which are apparently equal to each other, appears in a fraction.

$$\frac{(x+1)}{(x+1)} \times \frac{(x-3)}{(x-3)} \times \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x(x+4)}$$

**Step#3**

Using the property $\frac{ka}{kb}=\frac{a}{b}$, we have,

$$\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x(x+4)}$$

**Step#4**

Applying the *FOIL method* on two binomials in numerator place and some minor simplification give us,

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x(x+4)}$$

> **Note that** although we don't specify everywhere but we assume that *division by zero* is excluded.

Comment: this is wrong since $$x^2-x-6=(x+2)(x-3)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I have edited my answer now. Thanks for detection.

Answer (score 0):

i got the following expression $$\frac{x^2-4}{x(4+x)}$$

Comment: So is it alright to cancel out even though they aren't on the same plane?

Comment: @CaiSan  Observe that \begin{align*}\frac{x^2 - x - 2}{x^2 - 3x} \cdot \frac{x^2 - x - 6}{x^2 + 5x + 4} & = \frac{(x - 2)(x + 1)}{x(x - 3)} \cdot \frac{(x - 3)(x + 2)}{(x + 1)(x + 4)}\\ & = \frac{(x - 2)(x + 1)(x - 3)(x + 2)}{x(x - 3)(x + 1)(x + 4)}\end{align*} so you can cancel the factors of $x + 1$ and $x - 3$ that appear in both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{x^2-x-2}{x^2-3x} \cdot \frac{x^2-x-6}{x^2+5x+4}=
$$
$$
=\frac{(x+1)(x-2)}{x(x-3)} \cdot \frac{(x+2)(x-3)}{(x+1)(x+4)}=
$$
$$
=\frac{\color{blue}{(x+1)}(x-2)(x+2)\color{red}{(x-3)}}{x\color{red}{(x-3)}\color{blue}{(x+1)}(x+4)}=
$$
$$
=\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x(x+4)}=\frac{x^2-4}{x(x+4)}=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4x}
$$